# Why does Ethereum use JSON-RPC and not gRPC?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, json-rpc

I am fairly new to networking protocols especially JSON-RPC and gRPC as they are not nearly as common in web development as REST. I was reading around and seems like gRPC generally performs better. So why does Ethereum and other blockchains tend to use JSON-RPC and not gRPC?

Comment: Possibly for the same reason that Solidity does not support floating-point standard IEEE-754. It has to be executable (in the sense of "able to execute") on every possible client.

Comment: I don't know if there is a reason, but Ethereum started development in 2014 before grpc was introduced by google in 2015. Also json-rpc is more simple than grpc and less demanding.